# Spring data jpa query param LocalDate off a day in MySql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using LocalDate as a query param, but I always get the wrong result.

Springboot version 2.1.6.RELEASE

Mysql version 5.7

ps:
The application timezone is UTC+8(Asia/Shanghai)

MySql timezone also is UTC+8:

```sql
mysql> SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP);
+--------------------------------+
| TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP) |
+--------------------------------+
| 08:00:00                       |
+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Entity:

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Builder
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "DATE", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate createDate;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(columnDefinition = "DATETIME", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createTime;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(columnDefinition = "DATETIME", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime lastModifyTime;
}
```

Repository:

```java
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    List<User> findAllByCreateDate(LocalDate date);
}
```

springboot properties:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
        jdbc:
          time_zone: Asia/Shanghai
```

junit test:

```java
    @Test
    public void findAllByLocalDate() {
        userRepository.findAllByCreateDate(LocalDate.of(2019,7,25));
    }
```

when I run `findAllByCreateDate` the hibernate log is:

> Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_0_, user0_.create_date as create_d2_0_, user0_.create_time as create_t3_0_, user0_.last_modify_time as last_mod4_0_, user0_.name as name5_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.create_date=?
>   2019-07-25 16:28:39.172 TRACE 13880 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [DATE] - [2019-07-25]

It looks perfect. but when I check the MySql query log:

> 2019-07-25 16:28:39.327843000  root[root] @  [192.168.1.101]   270 0   Query   select user0_.id as id1_0_, user0_.create_date as create_d2_0_, user0_.create_time as create_t3_0_, user0_.last_modify_time as last_mod4_0_, user0_.name as name5_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.create_date='2019-07-24'

It minus a day in MySql.

ps: It only happen when LocalDate as query param, save and find work fine.

---

**My solution**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Component
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate locDate) {
        return locDate == null ? null : Date.valueOf(locDate);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date sqlDate) {
        return sqlDate == null ? null : sqlDate.toLocalDate();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you find the solution to the problem?

Comment: Same issue here..  any tip/solution?